# Public IP fronting a k8s Service has no DNS name in ACS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-service

I've created a k8s Service to publicly front my WebApi pod in my ACS Windows cluster. It works great but there is no DNS name associated with the Public IP resources that is created. This prohibits me from adding it as an endpoint for a Traffic Manager profile, roadblock!

I can manually assign a DNS name to the Public IP, but then I'd be touching an ACS created resource, which makes me uncomfortable. But I REALLY want a static DNS name and the features of TrafficMgr to be in front of it.

This feels like a significant deficiency. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a feature request in upstream
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50062

Answer (score 0):

When you create a service, Kubernete automatically create a dns for it as long as kube-dns is running.  The service name becomes the dns for accessing the pod withing the cluster and resolves to the cluster IP. So you can use the service name within other pods in the cluster.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#dns

Comment: Yes but this appears to only be useful for DNS within the cluster. I'm looking to expose the Service outside the cluster via DNS name so that I can connect other DNS cname mappings to it.

Comment: Sorry if i'm missing something here but in that case you can set `spec.type=LoadBalancer` in the service config block. This will create a Loadbalancer if you are using a cloud service. This will enable you to connect other DNS cname to it

Comment: TrafficManager requires a DNS name to point traffic to. The Azure cloud provider in Kubernetes does not set domain name on public IP. It requires manual update. I feel the pain as well. So I opened that issue in upstream. :)